# Data Change events- old value/new value information to change events

Tags: office-js

The Excel JavaScript API Open Specification @ https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/ExcelJs_OpenSpec indicates that for Data Change events-  old value/new value information has been added. This is in beta version of office.js. Looking for an example on how this is expected to work.

Comment: Please identify the specific APIs that you are asking about.

Comment: I am looking to see if the Binding OnDataChange will now have more than just Binding object for 'Table' Type

Answer (score 1):

This additional information in the Worksheet or Table onChanged event is rolling out now. ETA is April. This information is not added to the Binding object.

Comment: thank you.. Will check out the release when it comes out

Comment: The oldValue/newValue for onChanged event is already available. Please be aware that this only applies for changes happening on single cells. For multiple cells, these values are not provided.